# QLineEdit disappears after using .setEchoMode()

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have been trying to create a login screen and I tried to use a `QLineEdit` object to receive passwords, through `.setEchoMode()` but as soon as I use this function the whole field disappears in the UI.

If I leave the code like this the text field is still there:

```
uPass = QLineEdit()
layout.addRow('Password:', uPass)
```

[image]

But as soon as I add `.setEchoMode()` it disappears (the mode I use doesn't matter):

```
uPass = QLineEdit().setEchoMode(3)
layout.addRow('Password:', uPass)
```

[image]

Does anyone know what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: TYPO: use `uPass = QLineEdit()` `uPass.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.PasswordEchoOnEdit)` or `uPass = QLineEdit(echoMode=QLineEdit.PasswordEchoOnEdit)` 
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt doesn't support "function chaining" (which presumes that every function returns the instance), so you are not adding the line edit, but the value returned from `setEchoValue`, which is `None`.

Since QFormLayout supports adding empty fields, you're actually doing the following:

```
layout.addRow('Password:', None)
```

Change to:

```
uPass = QLineEdit()
uPass.setEchoMode(3)
layout.addRow('Password:', uPass)
```